# Invoking and executing stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql

In MySQL I have a table with name, address, telephone, age and charge column.

Assume I have written a stored procedure called
`calculate_monthly_charges`. This [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) takes no parameters.

How can I write a corresponding code for invoking and executing the stored procedure?

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CallStoredProcedureInMySql.htm).

Comment: 1. there are a number of answers to this question on Stackoverflow, and thousands on the web. 2. Stop using exclamation marks.

Comment: Have you actually looked at a tutorial on how to do this?  ... as I suggested to you two questions ago.

Comment: i see a lot of direct question from Johanna which can be googled first.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the MySQL documentation [Connector/J: Calling Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-examples-stored-procedure).